# How do I create a custom SynchronizationContext so that all continuations can be processed by my own single-threaded event loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Say you're writing a custom single threaded GUI library (or anything with an event loop). From my understanding, if I use `async/await`, or just regular TPL continuations, they will all be scheduled on `TaskScheduler.Current` (or on `SynchronizationContext.Current`).

The problem is that the continuation might want to access the single threaded parts of the library, which means it has to execute in the same event loop. For example, given a simple game loop, the events might be processed like this:

```
// All continuation calls should be put onto this queue
Queue<Event> events;

// The main thread calls the `Update` method continuously on each "frame"
void Update() {
    // All accumulated events are processed in order and the queue is cleared
    foreach (var event : events) Process(event);

    events.Clear();
}
```

Now given my assumption is correct and TPL uses the `SynchronizationContext.Current`, any code in the application should be able to do something like this:

```
async void Foo() {
    someLabel.Text = "Processing";

    await BackgroundTask();

    // This has to execute on the main thread
    someLabel.Text = "Done";
}
```

Which brings me to the question. **How do I implement a custom `SynchronizationContext` that would allow me to handle continuations on my own thread?** Is this even the correct approach?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Implementing a custom `SynchronizationContext` is not the easiest thing in the world. I have an open-source single-threaded implementation [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) that you can use as a starting point (or possibly just use in place of your main loop).

By default, `AsyncContext.Run` takes a single delegate to execute and returns when it is fully complete (since `AsyncContext` uses a custom `SynchronizationContext`, it is able to wait for `async void` methods as well as regular async/sync code).

```
AsyncContext.Run(async () => await DoSomethingAsync());
```

If you want more flexibility, you can use the `AsyncContext` advanced members (these do not show up in IntelliSense but they are there) to keep the context alive until some external signal (like "exit frame"):

```
using (var context = new AsyncContext())
{
  // Ensure the context doesn't exit until we say so.
  context.SynchronizationContext.OperationStarted();

  // TODO: set up the "exit frame" signal to call `context.SynchronizationContext.OperationCompleted()`
  // (note that from within the context, you can alternatively call `SynchronizationContext.Current.OperationCompleted()`

  // Optional: queue any work you want using `context.Factory`.

  // Run the context; this only returns after all work queued to this context has completed and the "exit frame" signal is triggered.
  context.Execute();
}
```

`AsyncContext`'s `Run` and `Execute` replace the current `SynchronizationContext` while they are running, but they save the original context and set that as current before returning. This allows them to work nicely in a nested fashion (e.g., "frames").

(I'm assuming by "frame" you mean a kind of WPF-like dispatcher frame).

Comment: Looks like you might be solving a more complicated problem than mine. I'm not doing any nesting, by frame I meant just a single call to render, rendering a single frame on a canvas. I wouldn't have any other synchronization context, just the one for the whole program. Which I guess should simplify things a bit?

Comment: @JakubArnold: Yes, you can just ignore the nesting part then. You'd still need to use `OperationStarted` to keep the main loop going until you get an "exit program" request.

Comment: But that's assuming the SynchronizationContext runs the loop, right? If I wanted to manually call onto the context to process its queue, wouldn't it be enough to override just `Post` to store into a queue?

Comment: `SynchronizationContext` never runs a loop;. If you want to build your own, you should override both `Post` and `Send`.

Comment: It seems like your Github project moved to https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx

Answer (score 0):

Although this question asks about a custom `SynchronizationContext`, the same functionality can be accomplished with a custom `TaskScheduler`. The `await` keyword captures either the [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) or the [`TaskScheduler.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current), and the continuation after the `await` will be send to the captured scheduler. The `SynchronizationContext` has a behavioral advantage over the `TaskScheduler` that I'll explain later, but a custom `TaskScheduler` can be implemented more easily. So let's see such an implementation:

```
public class SyncronizationTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler, IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Task> _queue = new();
    private int _pendingCount = 1;

    public static void Run(Func<Task> action)
    {
        using SyncronizationTaskScheduler scheduler = new();

        Task masterTaskUnwrapped = Task.Factory.StartNew(action,
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, scheduler)
            .Unwrap();

        scheduler.HandleTaskCompletion(masterTaskUnwrapped);

        foreach (var task in scheduler._queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            scheduler.TryExecuteTask(task);

        masterTaskUnwrapped.Wait(); // Propagate all exceptions
    }

    private void HandleTaskCompletion(Task task)
    {
        _ = task.ContinueWith(t => ErrorOnThreadPool(() =>
        {
            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref _pendingCount) == 0)
                _queue.CompleteAdding();
        }), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    private void ErrorOnThreadPool(Action action)
    {
        try { action(); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => throw new TaskSchedulerException(ex));
        }
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        ErrorOnThreadPool(() =>
        {
            int pending = Interlocked.Increment(ref _pendingCount);
            Debug.Assert(pending > 0);
            HandleTaskCompletion(task);
            _queue.Add(task);
        });
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task,
        bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) => false;

    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => 1;
    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks() => _queue;

    public void Dispose() => _queue.Dispose();
}
```

Usage example:

```
SyncronizationTaskScheduler.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Console.WriteLine($"After await on thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Console.WriteLine($"After await on thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
});
Console.WriteLine("SyncronizationTaskScheduler.Run completed");
```

Output:

```
After await on thread #1
After await on thread #1
SyncronizationTaskScheduler.Run completed
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y2FzPr)

The `SyncronizationTaskScheduler.Run` is a blocking call. It blocks the current thread until the completion of the asynchronous `action` delegate. The reason that the current thread must be blocked is because we need this thread to be available to run all the `await` continuations that have captured our custom scheduler. As you can see from the output of the program, both `await` continuations have ran on the thread #1, which is the main thread of the console application. The main thread was temporarily unblocked to run each continuation, and then blocked again until all the synchronous and asynchronous work initiated by the `action` was completed.

Concurrent operations are supported. You can launch many tasks inside the `action`, and all the `await` continuations of all the tasks will run on the current thread. Make sure to `await` all these tasks before exiting the `action` though.

The custom `TaskScheduler` above holds the scheduled tasks in a [`BlockingCollection<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) queue, much like Stephen Cleary's custom `SynchronizationContext` implementation ([`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/AsyncContext.cs)).

One interesting point of the above implementation is the `ErrorOnThreadPool` method. The [`QueueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.queuetask) method of the `TaskScheduler` has the habit of suppressing any exceptions that are thrown inside the body of the method, in which case the scheduler will just stop working and the `SyncronizationTaskScheduler.Run` would never return. The solution is to funnel any exception to the `ThreadPool`, so that the program can terminate with an unhandled exception (can be observed with the [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) event). Such an exception can only be raised when the `action` creates tasks and loses track of them, letting them become fire-and-forget. When these tasks try to schedule an `await` continuation after the completion of the `SyncronizationTaskScheduler.Run`, they'll find that the `BlockingCollection<Task>` has been disposed, resulting to an `ObjectDisposedException`. This is an incorrect usage of the scheduler. All tasks created by the `action` are expected to be awaited by the action itself, otherwise an unhandled `ObjectDisposedException` will be raised, and will crash the process. Which is bad, but arguably better than letting the process hang indefinitely without any error message whatsoever.

The behavioral disadvantage that the `SyncronizationTaskScheduler` has compared to Stephen Cleary's `AsyncContext`, is that it can't track the completion of any [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) operations launched by the `action`. The `SynchronizationContext` has an [`OperationCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.operationcompleted) method that is invoked appropriately by .NET's async infrastructure, and the `TaskScheduler` has nothing like this. So if you are dealing with `async void` operations, your only option is use a custom `SynchronizationContext` implementation.

Also be aware that any `await` configured with [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait) inside the `action` will not capture the scheduler, and the continuation will run on some other thread instead of the current thread. So use `ConfigureAwait(false)` only when you know for sure that there is no thread-affine code after the `await`.