# STA thread used in Winforms but not when executed as a Console app

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, wcf, callback

I have an assembly that runs under an STA thread within a sandbox from a third party, within this thread i have created a duplex WCF client that needs to execute methods on the original STA thread.

The current implementation works fine, within the Duplex callback i obtain the synchronization context of the STA thread as follows and use it to Post back to the STA thread:

```
private readonly SynchronizationContext _syncContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
```

This all runs within a WinForm initialised in the STA thread, great...but i need to move the WCF duplex proxy so it instead runs under a class instance within the main STA thread. When i remove the winform i end up getting a completely new thread from the above SynchronizationContext.

To clarify:

Winforms:-

- Start WCF Duplex Proxy on STA thread - ManagedThreadId = 1
- Receive duplex callback from server - ManagedThreadId = 5
- Post to callback event method using AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext - ManagedThreadId = 1

Without WinForm (class instance):-

- Start WCF Duplex Proxy on STA thread - ManagedThreadId = 1
- Receive duplex callback from server - ManagedThreadId = 6
- Post to callback event method using AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext - ManagedThreadId = 11

Executing on thread 11 instead of 1 means my methods fail to execute properly within the sandbox, there is no difference in the code between variants other than that one runs under a winform. Does anyone know how i can keep the duplex callback method execution in the main STA thread without using the winform?

Comment: Can you post your `Main` method? Without it the following diagnosis is supposition.  Your title says runs as a Console App and that has two potential sources.  The 1st is did you decorate the `Main` Method with [STAThread]?  The 2nd and more likely issue is that Console app does not install a synchronization context based on thread type;  when a context is created it is an instance of the SynchronizationContext Class and its [Post Method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs,16705ba05372139e,references) use the thread pool.

Comment: Why do you need an STA in the first place? Do you have COM objects involved? Can you use a form (even invisible) in your console app? If yes, you can use the sync context of this form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're acquiring the synchronization context using the `AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext` property. That property uses `SynchronizationContext.Current` under the hood.

That means, the obtained `SynchronizationContext` depends on the environment you're accessing the property in:

- the thread you're accessing the property on, and
- the type of the application.

As you can read [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The default implementation is the free-threaded implementation.

So, if the current thread's synchronization context is not set, you will get a default free-threaded `SynchronizationContext` instance. It will `Send` callbacks by synchronous execution on caller thread and `Post` callbacks to the `ThreadPool` (so "random" worker threads will pick them up).

In a Windows Forms app, the main thread's `SynchronizationContext` will be initialized to a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` instance for you. That instance will `Post` the callbacks to the main UI thread.

In a WPF app, this will be a `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`.

In a console app, there will be no `SynchronizationContext` for the main thread. Thus, the free-threaded option I mentioned above kicks in, so you get a free-threaded `SynchronizationContext` instance that posts to the `ThreadPool`. That pretty much explains the behavior you observe.

If you need that synchronization, you can implement your own thread-affine `SynchronizationContext` for the main thread of your console app. That is not easy though. In a console app, you have no message loop and no dispatcher that could manage the callback queue. You can take a look on this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39272758/2846483) by Stephen Cleary for an idea of an asynchronous `SynchronizationContext`. You will need to create a 'main loop' manually though.